# How to get the response of the soapclient function

Tags: php, soap-client

```
foreach ($record_sets as $row) {
    $params->Loginname = "a";
    $params->Password = "xxxxxxx";
    $params->studentresult = "<a1><marks>95</marks><grade>A</grade></a1>"; 
    $params->rollid = $row[0];

    $response = $client->Marksofstudent($params);
    $result = $response->Marksresult->SqlXml->any;

    var_dump($result);    

    /* NEED TO ALERT THE MESSAGE IF SOAP CLIENT FUNCTION RETURNS THE SUCCESS */
}
```

When i run this code, it uploads my data. When i var_dump the value it returns string(800) "". When i right click and check the view source , the below xml comes as per success and failure.

It returns the xml like 
`<ROOT ........."><t1><t2 rollid="76" marks="282"/></t1><Transfer><row TransferedrollID="5"/></Transfer></ROOT>` when success.

How could i alert to client if its uploads is successfull.

If its error, it returns the xml like  '`<ROOT ........."><t1><t2 rollid="76" eror="invalid roll number"/></ProcessLog></ROOT>'`

I just want to prompt the alert if its the xml is uploaded successfully as the xml comes as explained above and prompt error alert when the xml returned is as second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
if (strpos($result, 'eror') === false) echo 'Success!';
```

Another way:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
if (isset($xml->t1->t2->Transfer->row)) {
  echo 'Success!';
}
```

Comment: I like your second approach. Didn't know you could create a `SimpleXMLElement` this way. I was more planning of using `simplexml_load_string()` to get the job done, but this is much nicer.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have used the if (strpos($result, 'eror') === false) echo 'Success!'; 
and it worked successfully.